# Como Descompactar uma String compactada em GZip no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, gzip

Estou consultando as notas emitidas na SEFAZ, e no retorno, na tag doczip, recebemos um arquivo XML compactado em formato GZip, já tentei usando diversas bibliotecas, componentes e no final sempre recebo "Data Error". Consegui descompactar uma string de testes menor, mas o XML não descompacta de forma alguma. Não estou utilizando os componentes ACBr, mas tentei inclusive fazer a descompactação utilizando o mesmo método da Acbr mas tudo termina em um "Data Error". Alguém tem alguma dica ou rotina que faz essa descompressão de maneira correta?

Answer (score -2):

Depois de tanta luta, consegui resolver.
Caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema que eu, segue abaixo a solução:

```
decodeXML:= UnZip(DecodeBase64(xmlzip));
```

A função `Unzip` que utilizei está na Unit `pcnRetDistDFeInt` do projeto *ACBR* e o `DecodeBase64` que utilize está na unit `synacode`.

O problema que estava passando era que estava utilizando um `DecodeBase64` diferente.